# java compiler error in executable jar

Tags: java, exception, java-compiler-api

I have some problem with java compiler.

```
try
{
      JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
      DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
      StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
      Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("proccess/Main.java"));
      JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task=null;
      if(packagetrue==true)
      {
          fileManager.setLocation(javax.tools.StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("proccess")));
      }
      task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null,null, compilationUnits);
      success = task.call();                
      fileManager.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
      try
      {
            File err = new File("error.txt");
            java.io.PrintStream ps = new java.io.PrintStream(err);
            ex.printStackTrace(ps);
            ps.close();
      }
      catch(Exception exx){}
}
```

That code has been work, but it doesn't work in jar file.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The error in here :

```
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
```

What should I do ?
thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what makes you think the error lies in the line you give ?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main$14.run(Main.java:670)`,

line 670 is that error.

Comment: I think you run in a jre. That has no compiler. The compiler is part of the jdk

Comment: @Jens : any best way to out from my problem?

Comment: @newbie Install a jdk, set JAVA_HOME to it and run your program.

Comment: i have a jdk, and has been installed , u think how i can run my code ???

Comment: my project has been complete, I should make it a executable jar file.

Comment: can anyone fix my problem ?

Comment: How exactly do you run your jar file?

Comment: @ Sergey Petunin : double click in jar file.

Comment: @Jens : yes, u right, i have try using JDK by cmd, and it works.
how can i default running my jar on JDK ???

Comment: @newbie You can't. The jar is running with the JRE/JDK wich is configured in JAVA_HOME. Maybe it will be possible by wraping the start command with a script.

Comment: how to initialize java-home by command prompt ?